# merge all columns in the first column after the last row

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a tabular data like this one.

`1   4   7
 2   5   8
 3   6   9`

I would like data that look like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Does anyone know how to use pandas to do this. (or maybe the keyword for this methodology to search for since I don't know how to properly call the procedure.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df.T.stack()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy reshaping and pandas DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,1, order='F'))
```

Output:

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
6  7
7  8
8  9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)